# How to only step through 'my' Java source code when using Intellij's debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to understand a small Java codebase that I have been given, by stepping through the program with Intellij's debugger. I began at the 'main' function, and continually pressed 'step into' to execute each line of code. However, the debugger soon started stepping into 'Application.class' and 'Thread.java'. I only want to step through the source code that I have been given.

I looked up this question and the solution was to add entries in settings->debugger->stepping->'Do not step into class', but the debugger still steps into these classes and is making it impossible for me to step through the source code to get an understanding of how it works.

Comment: I tried keep pressing "step into" and it doesn't step into the `Thread` class... Anyway, how about stepping out whenever you get into one of those classes?

Comment: Note that the button next to 'Step Into' is 'Step Over', which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Function keys makes things much easier.

Use the F8 Function Key to step through your code and when you want to go through the invoked method from your code, use F7.